# Angular NVD3 library error

Tags: d3.js, error-handling, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I am working with NVD3 library and I added the links to the libraries that I need.I have the v3 for D3 and the angular NVD3 link, but the chart is not rendering and I get an error like below.

This are the links in my index file:

```
 <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/novus/nvd3/v1.8.1/build/nv.d3.js</script> 
<script src="dist/angularjs-nvd3-directives.js"></script>
```

And here is my error:

```
angularjs-nvd3-directives.js:1377 Uncaught TypeError: nv.models.multiBarChart(...).width(...).height(...).margin(...).x(...).y(...).forceY(...).showLegend(...).showControls(...).showXAxis(...).showYAxis(...).tooltips(...).reduceXTicks(...).staggerLabels(...).noData(...).rotateLabels(...).color(...).delay is not a function(…)
```

Does anybody have any ideas on how to solve this ?

Sample Code.

```
     <nvd3-multi-bar-chart data='data'
        height="400" showXAxis="true" showYAxis="true" showLegend="true"
        xAxisLabel="xAxisLabel" yAxisLabel="yAxisLabel"
       yAxisTickFormat="yAxisTickFormatFunction()"  legendPosition="left"
       stacked="true" interactive="true" showControls="false" showValues="true "
       tooltips="false" tooltipcontent="toolTipContentFunction()" padding="50">
    <svg></svg>
 </nvd3-multi-bar-chart>
```

Comment: Please edit your post with the code, the script tags are not enough.

Comment: It seems like `delay` is not function of `nv.models.multiBarChart()`